# noHandlerFound when unit testing login powered by Spring security

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-security, mockmvc

I'm getting this error when submitting login form with unit test:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/login/authenticate] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
```

I'm using Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE with Spring Security 4.0.0.M1.

This is how I have configured my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        UnitTestContext.class,
        SecurityContext.class,
        ServletContext.class
})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LoginControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;
    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvcHtmlUnitDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webAppContext)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
        webDriver = new MockMvcHtmlUnitDriver(mockMvc);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        LoginPage loginPage = LoginPage.get(webDriver).login(LoginPage.class);
    }

}
```

Login page class:

```
public class LoginPage extends AbstractPage {

    public static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/app/login";

    @FindBy(id = "username")
    private WebElement usernameElement;
    @FindBy(id = "password")
    private WebElement passwordElement;
    @FindBy(id = "remember-me")
    private WebElement rememberMeElement;
    @FindBy(id = "login-btn")
    private WebElement loginBtnElement;
    @FindBy(id = "login-form")
    private WebElement loginForm;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver webDriver) {
        super(webDriver);
    }

    public LoginPage typeUsername(String username) {
        usernameElement.sendKeys(username);
        return this;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return usernameElement.getAttribute("value");
    }

    public LoginPage typePassword(String password) {
        passwordElement.sendKeys(password);
        return this;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return passwordElement.getAttribute("value");
    }

    public LoginPage selectRememberMe() {
        rememberMeElement.click();
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isRememberMe() {
        return rememberMeElement.isSelected();
    }

    public <T> T login(Class<T> resultPage) {
        loginBtnElement.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, resultPage);
    }

    public static LoginPage get(WebDriver webDriver) {
        webDriver.get(URL);
        return PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, LoginPage.class);
    }

}
```

And here's `SecurityContext.class` where I have declared the `/login/authenticate` mapping:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/static/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers();

        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/loginfailed"));
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl(userMapper);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

}
```

-

```
@Configuration
public class UnitTestContext {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setBasenames(
                "i18n/messages",
                "i18n/validation-messages");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return Mockito.mock(UserService.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserMapper userMapper() {
        return Mockito.mock(UserMapper.class);
    }

}
```

-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.app.common.controller",
        "com.app.home.controller",
        "com.app.user.controller"
})
public class ServletContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/")
                .setCachePeriod((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(365));
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setAdditionalDialects(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                new SpringSecurityDialect())));

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver =
                new ServletContextTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return templateResolver;
    }

}
```

Login page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:include="layouts/main-layout :: main-layout">
<head>
    <title th:text="#{login.page.title}"></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" th:fragment="content">
        <form class="default-form" method="post" action="login/authenticate" role="form"
                th:object="${loginForm}">
            <input type="hidden"
                th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <div class="default-form-header">
                <h3 th:text="#{login.header.text}"></h3>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" th:text="#{login.username.label}"></label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text"
                            id="username"
                            class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{username}"
                            th:maxlength="${usernameMaxLength}"
                            th:placeholder="#{login.username.label}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" th:text="#{login.password.label}"></label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="password"
                            id="password"
                            class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{password}"
                            th:maxlength="${passwordMaxLength}"
                            th:placeholder="#{login.password.label}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                id="remember-me" />
                            <span th:text="#{login.remember.checkbox}"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="default-form-footer">
                <button type="submit"
                    id="login-btn"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    th:text="#{login.submit.button}">
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works nice when it's running on Tomcat. Am I missing some filter or what?

While debugging I found out that `urlMap` in `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping` contains only these urls: (/login/authenticate is missing)

```
{
    /=[{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}],
    /loginfailed=[{[/loginfailed],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}],
    /login=[{[/login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}],
    /signup=[{[/signup],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]},
    {[/signup],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
}
```

This is what comes from print()

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = GET
         Request URI = /app/login
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[*/*;charset=ISO-8859-1], Accept=[image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, */*], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate], Accept-Language=[en-us]}

             Handler:
                Type = com.app.user.controller.LoginController
              Method = public java.lang.String com.app.user.controller.LoginController.showLoginPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = null

        ModelAndView:
           View name = login
                View = null
           Attribute = usernameMaxLength
               value = 30
           Attribute = passwordMaxLength
               value = 30
           Attribute = loginForm
               value = com.app.user.dto.LoginForm@fa8227
              errors = []

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8]}
        Content type = text/html; charset=UTF-8
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
kesäkuuta 01, 2014 9:10:51 AP. org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/login/authenticate] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /app/login/authenticate
          Parameters = {_csrf=[12e09c07-32f7-4dee-8ad0-35bfa1827354], username=[], password=[]}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[*/*;charset=UTF-8], Accept=[*/*], Referer=[http://localhost:8080/app/login], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate], Accept-Language=[en-us]}

             Handler:
                Type = null

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = null

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 404
       Error message = null
             Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

Comment: can you post your web.xml as well

Comment: I don't have web.xml, full java config. I have updated my question to include all configuration classes.

Comment: I see a prefix of /app/ in the Exception, the unit test is not aware about app name.

Comment: can you try '/login/authenticate' instead of 'app/login/authenticate'?

Comment: @Haim, I don't think that's the case, because when GETting the login page and printing out current url I get this: http://localhost:8080/app/login

Comment: @Javakid my form action is set to `login/authenticate`

Comment: @Perak Can you post your log in page and your test? The error is that Spring Security is not matching on the request (typically Spring Security's filter processes the request not an MVC mapping) and Spring MVC is not finding the mapping. Likely it is not matching due to a context root issue. You might also add MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).alwaysDo(print()) and post the logging from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the HmtlUnitRequestBuilder in how it is converting from HtmlUnit's request to Spring's MockHttpServletRequest. You can find additional details in [spring-test-mvc-htmlunit/issues/28](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc-htmlunit/issues/28).

I have pushed out a fix to master so you can [update to the latest snapshot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc-htmlunit#updating-dependencies) of spring-test-mvc-htmlunit to resolve your issue.